# Protect the values in Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, security, proxy

Is there a way to protect the values in Ajax Request in a JSP?
Proxy tools like Paros Proxy, are able to intercept the Ajax Request values and modifying the values.

One solution will be to encrypt the Ajax request values in Javascript before being intercepted by the proxy tool and decrypt the values at Server.

But since there are hundreds of Jsp's in the application with Ajax requests, this is probably not the best solution to encrypt the values in each jsp manually.

Can this be acheived using any other alternative?

Comment: Encrypt to protect the parameters from whom? The user or some potential attacker sniffing the network traffic?

Comment: The only out-of-the-box, end-to-end encryption solution would be HTTPS but it sounds like Paros can intercept that too. I doubt you'll be able to ensure no one modifies your data without explicitly encrypting on the client and explicitly decrypting on the server for each script.

Comment: Yes to protect the params from sniffing. If encryption and decryption is the only way, is it possible to do it only once for all jsp, something like interceptor, but interceptor or filters will not work in this case.